# Emit multiple pairs in map operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have rows of phone call records the format:

```
[CallingUser, ReceivingUser, Duration]
```

If I want to know the total amount of time that a given user has been on the phone (sum of Duration where the User was the CallingUser or the ReceivingUser).

Effectively, for a given record, I would like to create 2 pairs `(CallingUser, Duration)` and `(ReceivingUser, Duration)`.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I can add 2 `RDDs` together, but I am unclear if this is a good approach:

```
#Sample Data:
callData = sc.parallelize([["User1", "User2", 2], ["User1", "User3", 4], ["User2", "User1", 8]  ])


calls = callData.map(lambda record: (record[0], record[2]))

#The potentially inefficient map in question:
calls += callData.map(lambda record: (record[1], record[2]))


reduce = calls.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want flat map. If you write a function that returns the list `[(record[0], record[2]),(record[1],record[2])]` then you can flat map it!

Comment: Care to provide the line of code to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Use a flatMap() which is good for taking single inputs and generating multiple mapped outputs.  Complete with code:

```
callData = sc.parallelize([["User1", "User2", 2], ["User1", "User3", 4], ["User2", "User1", 8]])

calls = callData.flatMap(lambda record: [(record[0], record[2]), (record[1], record[2])])
print calls.collect()
# prints [('User1', 2), ('User2', 2), ('User1', 4), ('User3', 4), ('User2', 8), ('User1', 8)]

reduce = calls.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
print reduce.collect()
# prints [('User2', 10), ('User3', 4), ('User1', 14)]
```